# Enumerate all n-tuples of digits from 0 to 9 in Python

Tags: python, numbers

Playing around with some number theory problems. I would like a way to loop (n-times) over all the digits from 0 to 9, given n.

Assuming an easier way is to first generate all the tuples and loop over them once, what is the quickest way (in Python) to generate all n-tuples with elements the digits from 0 to 9? E.g. for n=2, (0,0), (0,1), (0,2)...(9,8),(9,9).

Comment: `itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(10), 2)`

Comment: The suggested code snippet does not explore all possible tuples.

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools

def func(n):
    for v in itertools.product(range(10),repeat=n):
        print(v)
func(2)
```